# SAS Output Returning Different Value

Tags: sas

I have the following SAS code that's using data from the American Communities Survey from the Census:

```
  if year2<2018 then do; if gasp=3 then gasp2=0; else if gasp>3 then gasp2=gasp; end;
   else if year2>=2018 then do; if gasfp="3" then gasp2=0; else if gasfp="4" then gasp2=gasp; end;
  if year2<2018 then do; if elep=2 then elep2=0; else if elep>2 then elep2=elep; end;
   else if year2>=2018 then do; if elefp="2" then elep2=0; else if elefp="3" then elep2=elep; end;
  if year2<2018 then do; if watp=2 then watp2=0; else if watp>2 then watp2=watp; end;
   else if year2>=2018 then do; if watfp="2" then watp2=0; else if watfp="3" then watp2=watp; end;
  if year2<2018 then do; if fulp=2 then fulp2=0; else if fulp>2 then fulp2=fulp; end;
   else if year2>=2018 then do; if fulfp="2" then fulp2=0; else if fulfp="3" then fulp2=fulp; end;
  GRNTP=gasp2 + elep2 + watp2/12 + fulp2/12;
  if year2 = 2019 then GRNTP;
```

It produces the following output:

| GRNTP |
| --- |
| 698966477 |

However, when I sum the value of of the individual columns they return a different result:

| GASP2 | ELEP2 | WATP2/12 | FULP2/12 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 155826234 | 496821614 | 126975649 | 26472227 | 806095724 |

Can someone explain why this is happening, and how to fix?

Comment: That last statement is not valid SAS syntax.  You need a statement, not a variable after the THEN.

Comment: Please provide the underlying raw data.